# cannot display result when query sql based on user input in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

From the title you may know that I cannot get the result when I query from sql database.
Here is my code :

```
public string Summon(int Input1)
{
    SqlDataAdapter dbadapter = null;
    DataSet returnDS = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(
        "DatabaseConnection"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        //string sqlQuery = "select * from SUMMON";

        string sqlQuery = "select * from SUMMON where ic_no=@Input1";

        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        cmd.Connection = dbconn;
        dbadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        dbadapter.Fill(returnDS);
    }

    return returnDS.GetXml();
}
```

Then I get this exception :-

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@Input1".

Comment: You should not edit your question to include the answer. Just click the big checkmark button next to the answer to say it's the right one.

Comment: sorry, I did not edit my question, I didnot put the answer on that?..why you say like that?..anyway, thanks for the info..:)

Comment: It's alright, you're here to learn, like all of us. You had edited the question at the top, adding the answer below, separating with many `@` characters. I rolled back to the version before and formatted a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a parameter named @Input1 to cmd:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Input1", input1));
```

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) explains how to use parameters with data adaptors.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input1", Input1);
string sqlQuery = "select * from SUMMON where ic_no='Input1'";

Comment: I made that but still cannot the get output in xml.

Comment: it thrown this exception :: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Int32 objects.

Comment: I've changed the answer to construct a new SqlParameter. Documentation for SqlParameterCollection is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wce29x9(v=vs.90).aspx